# SetDllDirection under win8 IE10 failed?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

My code is a plugin for IE, and the plugin will delay load some DLLs. 
I have put all my DLLs in the folder

> C:\users\myUser\Appdata\Roaming

When initializing the plugin, I will call win32 API `SetDllDirectory` to set my DLL directory. Hoever, under win8 and IE10, load DLL always fails. After my research, system will add additional path if you set DLL directory under `C:\Users\myUser\appdata`.

For example:

```
SetDllDirectory("C:\Users\myUser\appdata\Roaming");
```

The expected result is when I call GetDllDirectory`, I will get string like

> C:\Users\myUser\appdata\Roaming

But actually, GetDllDirectory will return

> C:\Users\myUser \Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Virtualized\ C:\Users\myUser\appdata\Roaming

I can only reproduce this issue under win8 and IE10.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Injecting DLLs into the browser from a folder that any program can write to is asking for trouble.  The protected mode feature in IE puts an end to it.  Some background [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2007/02/12/638372.aspx)

Comment: Thanks your comments, Hans. But I found if I check the "Allow active content to run in files on My computer" in Advance tab in Internet Options. SetDllDirectory works well. But in IE9 and IE8 the option is also unchecked but SetDllDirection still can work well.

Comment: AFAIK this is by design in windows 8.
In windows 8.1 it seems (I'm just guessing here, since Microsoft is insisting on not publishing any kind of useful information), that you have full access to C:\Users\myUser\Local\Packages\windows_ie_ac_001.